# How to expose a .NET environment via an API on localhost and output search data

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, browser, localhost

Good day, I am trying to accomplish entering a .NET environment via an API, and create search filters that will output data from a single 'Employee table'.

My main goal is to enter this .NET project through an API or browser and perform search outputs on a table.

The Employee table is imported from a local .JSON file, and stored in a List array.
I have managed to traverse that array, in a Windows Form using c# -
This was done in a separate project and NOT in the project currently displayed.

Now, I am struggling to visualize the next step, of entering the environment
via an API. I aim to preferably enter via a local ASP page,
though Angular, PostMan or even Android are acceptable.

*My question:*
How would I expose this .NET environment via an API?
How could I test this locally on Windows, using Visual Studio and a browser?

(PS. Also, I am wondering, is this project ready to compile in its Current Form?
Is it meant to be launched on a localhost, or is it meant to be a binary file?

Because, When I press compile & debug, it produces an error saying it can't find the binary file in the 'net5.'0 folder. However, I suspect I might not have the complete5.0 framework installed, or, it's because the code isn't saved in the default \Users folder and might not have permission to create a new file.
PLEASE NOTE: That the fact the code won't compile is not the issue.
I am asking for help to guide me upon how I would begin creating an entrance point into the current project, via an API)
)

I will post the base code of the visual studio project I was given to work on:

**PROGRAM.CS**
Here is the program.cs file, with the static main, which launches the following 'startup.cs' file

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SenwesAssignment_API
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

**STARTUP.CS**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SenwesAssignment_API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "SenwesAssignment_API", Version = "v1" });
                c.AddSecurityDefinition("bearerAuth", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                    Scheme = "bearer",
                    BearerFormat = "JWT",
                    Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
                });
                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "bearerAuth" }
                        },
                        new string[] {}
                    }
                });
                var xmlFile = "API.XML";
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "SenwesAssignment_API v1"));
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**EmployeeController.cs**

Here is the employeeController.cs file and I can see that something meaningful must be inserted here, which would allow something to enter and traverse the current environment:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using SenwesAssignment_API.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SenwesAssignment_API.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class EmployeeController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<EmployeeController> _logger;
        private readonly LoadData _loadData;

        public EmployeeController(ILogger<EmployeeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _loadData = new LoadData();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get all employees
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Returns a list of all employees</returns>
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            var employeeData = _loadData.LoadEmployeeData();
            return Ok(employeeData);
        }

        
        [Route("Get/{empId}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetByEmployeeId(int empId)
        {
            var employee = _loadData.LoadEmployeeData().Where(x => x.EmpID == empId).FirstOrDefault();
            return Ok(employee);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, to be consistent, here is the page that lifts the data from the JSON file.
A List array is produced, which in turn returns an IEnumerable object - which I have no problem in navigating.
**LoadData.cs**

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
    namespace SenwesAssignment_API.Data
    {
        public class LoadData
        {
            private List<Employee> _empData;
    
            public LoadData()
            {
                _empData = null;
            }
            
    
            public IEnumerable<Employee> LoadEmployeeData()
            {
                if (_empData == null)
                {
                    string jsonFilePath = @"Data\Employee.json";
                    string json = File.ReadAllText(jsonFilePath);
    
                    _empData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(json);
                }
                
                return _empData;
            }
        }
    }
```

My question, repeated again: How would I simulate on a localhost, entering a .NET environment via a browser or API, and output search filter results?

Thank you for your time, and forgive my approach, since I've never attempted this before.

Comment: It seems like everything works if you manage to run it, please post a specific error. Your title and almost every information you gave has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: I haven't managed to run it. I merely lifted the code that imports the .JSON database.
I am asking for guidance on how to treat this project. How or in what way would I host it, and begin creating an entrance point.

How I would expose this code and then, create Filters for certain types of output.

EDIT: The problem is not that it won't compile. The problem is that I don't know how to begin creating an entrance point, or in fact, how to treat this project and code to begin approaching it via an API

Comment: It is pointed out in your controller, [Route("Get/{empId}")] that means you already have an entrance point, you can access it from your browser or from postman etc etc if you make an HTTP GET request at (for example) localhost:porthere/Get/1234 and you can easily see the specific URL if you run it. What seems to be the issue?

Comment: ok, thank you for that.
I am getting closer to understanding what's going on..

Forgive me, if I sound like I'm wanting spoon-fed help. 
and PS: Yes there was a compile error, and it's due to me running Visual Studio 2017, and not 2019, which of course, doesn't support .NET 5.0. Ok so those entities there in the controller must be used to enter via my browser, or PostMan. Thank you

Comment: @Costa

Costa, you're still there? The program compiles and runs, then a browser windows opens into 'http://localhost:5000/swagger/index.html'.

Inside the 'Bin' folder there's also 'api.xml', referenced in the startup.cs file.

I'm unable to find the index.html file.

If someone can show me how to enter the correct parameters and address into the address bar, so that I could for example see the output of the returned IActionResult entity, of the [Route("Get/{empId}")] , seen in the controller, then I can finish the exercise